# Idiom or phrase for a situation where someone asks for advice from the worst possible person?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

You found that one of your friends is asking some advice from someone, but you find it hilarious because that someone is the worst adviser in the history of the universe, even though there are many good people available to take advice from.

Answer (score 26):

"[**The blind leading the blind**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_blind_leading_the_blind)."

*From Wikipedia:* The blind leading the blind is used to describe a situation where a person who knows nothing is getting advice and help from another person who knows almost nothing.

Example: "Alice just bought her first car and is asking Bob for driving tips. I don't know why, since Bob is infamous for how often he gets caught violating traffic laws. It's the blind leading the blind."

Comment: What @P. E. Dant said. I'm not normally a big fan of *How do I express this in idiomatic English?* questions, but this answer is *so* indisputably the most common turn of phrase it's well worth learners taking it on board.

Comment: IMHO this phrase describes the situation after the "asking advice" part.

Answer (score 1):

The pig asking the butcher. The sheep asking the wolf.

Comment: Can you explain what these mean rather than just listing them here? While this may be a good suggestion, it's much more useful to tell us how this relates to the question.

Comment: These fit the title question, but not the full-text question. These obviously put malice on the side of the one being asked, where the situation the OP describes more likely involves ineptitude than malice.

Answer (score -1):

*"barking the wrong tree?"*

That is.. when a question is directed to a person who was assumed to be in the know of what is queried about, and his response turns out disappointingly lacking in the needed clarity, it makes the enquirer regret his/her own misjudgment in approaching the said person in the first place..

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: The phrase is *'barking UP the wrong tree'* and it means making an incorrect assumption, not asking an inappropriate person for advice.

Comment: The assumption has to be *about something*. Asking or barking up a tree ( in gerund form ) can be used in its verb form in this context  indicating the act of asking or barking up or down a tree of incorrect choice.

Comment: @Narasimham Idioms... don't *exactly* work like that. They're only usually understood if they have a *very* specific phrasing.

Comment: This answer seems to be an _example_ of the blind leading the blind!

Comment: @dotancohen et al. - Though not an exact match, it's still a related expression that could be used. I can see where the O.P. is going with this. _"You asked **Dave** for advice? You're barking up the wrong tree."_

Comment: I think this would be a good answer if the idiom was expressed correctly (barking UP the wrong tree) and there was an example sentence similar to the one @J.R. mentioned in his comment. It might also be good to link to a reference that explains the idiom, like http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Barking+Up+the+Wrong+Tree

Comment: Yes, I somehow missed the *up* part. I indicated generally that it is a misplaced search area for some needed goal or ojective. It could be asking for advice from a person  not knowing he is not the right guide, it could be a team of doctors spending a lot of time  discussing a wrong disease during diagnosis blunder of a disease afflicting a patient, or digging for oil at an area not so well prospected and so on...